# Best way to create a masking of dummy variables?

Tags: python, pandas

So for example I have a pandas DataFrame that contains a column of city names and I already have a large predefined list of city names that will be used as dummy variables in a model. I would like for each city name in the list to be added as a new column and then filled with a bunch of 0s and 1s where a string in the city name column matches the column name of the dummy variable.

From my perspective, I would need to do something along the lines of:

```
for dv in dummy_var_list:
    df[dv] = df[df[city_names]==dv]
```

I am unsure if this would be an efficient or correct approach. I would need to incorporate some sort of 'if' statement or masking which I am unsure of how to do.

i.e. I have list of city names:

```
['paris','sydney','orlando','milwaukee']
```

and I have a list of predefined dummies I need to make columns of:

```
['tokyo','berlin','beijing','orlando','paris']
```

So some rows will not have any '1's in them because there is no match, but that is ok.

Comment: Can you please produce a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 1):

If you are only interested in certain cities, you can just take the subset of your dataframe that contains the cities you are interested in, take the dummy columns of that using `pd.dummies`, and then join with the original dataframe:

```
>>> df
  city_names
0      Paris
1   New York
2      Paris
3      Tokyo
4   New York

dummy_var_list = ['Paris', 'New York']

dummy_df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.loc[df.city_names.isin(dummy_var_list)], 
                   prefix='', prefix_sep='')).fillna(0)

>>> dummy_df
  city_names  New York  Paris
0      Paris       0.0    1.0
1   New York       1.0    0.0
2      Paris       0.0    1.0
3      Tokyo       0.0    0.0
4   New York       1.0    0.0
```

**Edit**: If I understand correctly, you want a dummy column for all your cities in `dummy_var_list`, even if they don't show up in `city_names` in your original `df`. In that case, after the code above, you could loop through and add a column of zeros for cities that didn't show up:

```
>>> df
  city_names
0      Paris
1   New York
2      Paris
3      Tokyo
4   New York

dummy_var_list = ['Paris', 'New York', 'Los Angeles']

dummy_df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.loc[df.city_names.isin(dummy_var_list)], 
        prefix='', prefix_sep='')).fillna(0)

for i in dummy_var_list:
    if i not in dummy_df.columns:
        dummy_df[i] = 0 

>>> dummy_df
  city_names  New York  Paris  Los Angeles
0      Paris       0.0    1.0            0
1   New York       1.0    0.0            0
2      Paris       0.0    1.0            0
3      Tokyo       0.0    0.0            0
4   New York       1.0    0.0            0
```

Comment: Yeah I would do that; however, in order for my model to work the number of variables in the dataframe need to match up, meaning I can't just use get_dummies.

Comment: I believe that would leave me only with columns that would already be in the city names column and not the complete list of dummy variables (it would filter them out). Or am I interpreting it incorrectly?

Comment: Not quite. I already have a separate (much larger) list of city names that I need to use to make columns on the dataframe with. So certain cities in the city name column on the dataframe may not have a match (i.e. a row of all zeroes, but that is ok).

Comment: I think it would be different. Let's say Tokyo is in the dummy_var_list and not in the city names column. Would it still add a column for Tokyo containing all zeroes?

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Also: I used merge instead of join because I didn't have to specify suffixes with it unlike join.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so:

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['tokyo','berlin','beijing','orlando','paris'])
df['city'] = ['paris','sydney','orlando','milwaukee']
```

Initial df:

```
  tokyo berlin beijing orlando paris       city
0   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN      paris
1   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN     sydney
2   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN    orlando
3   NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN   NaN  milwaukee

for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df['city'] == col, col] = 1
df = df.replace(np.NaN, 0)
```

Output:

```
   tokyo  berlin  beijing  orlando  paris       city
0      0       0        0        0      1      paris
1      0       0        0        0      0     sydney
2      0       0        0        1      0    orlando
3      0       0        0        0      0  milwaukee
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I will try that as well, thanks